# Skin for org.richfaces Calender component Only

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf, richfaces

I am using richfaces calender component. I am using **bootstrap** for styling.

In the **web.xml**, I am adding

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
<context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
        <param-value>plain</param-value>
</context-param>
```

However, this leaves my calendar control to look transparent, as below.
[image: transparent looking richfaces calendar control]

How can I change only the skin of calendar component? Or do I have any other alternative, simple to use calendar component along with my JSF & bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the bootstrap styles to apply to the calendar you'll have to style it yourself. Otherwise you can use the RichFaces skins - other than "plain" which doesn't style anything. There isn't a skin just for the calendar, the skins apply to all components but they won't overwrite the styles of your own elements.

Comment: Okay, but I have also no clue on how to style it. I mean what components of the calendar must be specified in the css. Any guidance or example, I shall appreciate.

Comment: See the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html_single/#__literal_rich_calendar_literal).

Comment: Okay, thank you so much. I will try this & respond accordingly.

Comment: Did not quite understand how to proceed on this. Any sample code will be great help!